# Facebook feed generation

Tags: xml, facebook, feed, facebook-instant-articles, facebook-feed

I am trying to generate an xml for facebook feed using php with utm parameters. The  xml is generated with utm parameters in the link tag but when going to that post in facebook page and clicking on the post, utm parameter is not attached with it. It only opens the main url and not appending the url parameters. Please help me out with this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably due to the `og:url` meta or canonical URL not having that parameter included in the first place …

Comment: still not working. I can see the utm parameters in the xml created for facebook instant article, but not in the post shown on the facebook page.